# Swift & SpriteKit: Full screen image

Tags: ios, swift, resize, sprite-kit

I'm making a first scene with SpriteKit in swift. I created a background image for 4 inch iPhone with dimensions 640x1136. I placed the image as sprite in centre of the screen, but the image is not full screen, there are edges missing.

Next, I tried to resize the image within app. When I did `image.size.height = self.size.height` the height got properly resized along full iPhone screen.
But when I did the same with width `image.size.width = self.size.width` then the picture got extremely stretched width wise.

I printed the dimensions of `self.size` and it turns out the dimension for my iPhone 5s are 1024, 768. This is total nonsense as the screen can't be wider than its height on iPhone. The app is universal but the only orientation is set to portrait.

Edit: This is the code I use to put the image on the screen

```
class GameScene: SKScene
{
    let menuImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "menuImage")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        menuImage.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        menuImage.size.height = self.size.height
        menuImage.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        self.addChild(menuImage)
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your simulator is not iPhone 5s ?

Comment: I test it both on my iPhone 5s and a simulator of iPhone 5s and they do the same thing

Comment: Why did you make your image 640 * 1136 if it need to be 768 * 1024 ?

Comment: I then recreated the image with the dimensions of 768 * 1024 and tried the same thing. This time, the image was "zoomed out" again, but it wasn't even proportional to the screen anymore

Besides, the 4 inch retina display has the 640 * 1136 resolution.
[link](http://www.theverge.com/2012/9/12/3321044/apple-iphone-5-retina-display-update)Source

Comment: Paste your code how do you add the image onto your scene. 640 x 1136 is the correct size for iPhone 5/5S screen. Also, do you change `SKScene`'s `scaleMode` property? Which size do you use to instaniate `SKScene`?

Comment: Try with 320x568 it's working for me

Comment: I posted the code. I don't change the scaleMode as I'm not sure how it works. Its set to aspectFill for default.

I'll try the 320 * 568

Comment: I changed the resolution to 320 * 568 and I have the same problem as with the higher resolution. I'm posting a screenshot for you to see.

http://i.imgur.com/Hvt3zND.png

Comment: In your gameViewController file do you have: scene.size = skView.bounds.size just before skView.presentScene(scene)

Comment: and try self.frame.size.height and not self.size.height

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have `scene.size = skView.bounds.size`
That made it work, even though I don't know what that means. Would you please mind explaining?

if you do, please write it in an answer so I can mark it as the best one. Thanks!

Comment: Can i post as a answer and you could make it the response please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add

`scene.size = skView.bounds.size`

or for Swift 5

`scene.size = self.view.bounds.size`

just before `skView.presentScene(scene)` in your gameViewController file

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem with wrong resizing.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me to stretch the background image to fit the whole screen in Swift 5.

```
background.size = CGSize (width: frame.maxX, height: frame.maxY)
```